# How to create an unnested folder?

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'm running Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.65 (22091101). I am trying to create a new folder in my Outlook account. I want this folder to be unnested – i.e., for it to be at the same level as “Inbox”, “Drafts”, “Clutter” etc.

I used to be able to do this without any difficulty, by using the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. However, lately, this shortcut now creates a subfolder within the folder that I currently have open. If I'm on my inbox, for example, and try to create a new folder, it creates a subfolder within my inbox. Trying the same via the menu bar > file > new> folder achieves the same result. (Interestingly the “folder at this level” option is unavailable.) I can only assume that Microsoft Outlook for Mac has been recently updated and this behaviour has been changed.

So, how can I create an unnested folder? Is it possible to reverse to the old behaviour of Outlook for the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's suggested that you could create the new folder at the same level as “Inbox” via the following steps:

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I'm blind. Therefore my screen reader can't transcribe the image you posted. Would you mind writing the steps as text?

Comment: Create a top-level folder:
1.Right-click on your email address in the left folder menu and select New Folder. 2.The folder will appear at the bottom of your list of folders and called Untitled Folder. You can rename it by right-clicking it and selecting Rename Folder.
3.You can also move the folder by clicking and dragging it to your preferred position and then letting go of the mouse button.

Comment: References: Create a top-level folder(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-a-folder-in-outlook-for-mac-71948772-18f5-4ef6-b8a4-396e70d70598#:~:text=Create%20a%20top%2Dlevel%20folder)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Thanks for checking, Christy. Again, as I'm blind, answers that involve the mouse aren't doable for me. I'm waiting to have a sighted person to assist me. If you can think of a way to do it via the menus/keyboard shortcuts, that'd be great. My screen reader (VoiceOver) does simulate a right click of the mouse, but when I do it on my email account, it opens the contextual menu as if I were performing a right click on the inbox.

Comment: I'm afraid that we cannot create the folder as the same level as Inbox folder via menus. Maybe you can try to create a folder on web mail and then sync to Outlook client.